# How to display multiple videos selected from gallery on screen in Flutter App ,using file_picker package?

Tags: flutter, dart

Using file_picker package in flutter, Able to select multiple videos from gallery,
How to display those videos on App screen in flutter.
I am using : https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/blob/master/file_picker/example/lib/src/file_picker_demo.dart

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using either a Grid view or a sliver grid view.
When you pick these multiple images, save them to a list. My suggestion is you use the video thumbnail plugin to make thumbnails for these videos and put them in the grid. Use a stack to add an "x" icon at the top of each thumbnail so that a user is able to deselect a video that he has selected.

Comment: Thanks  Simeon, saving images in list I am able to get it on screen.